# mapbox Location picker I cannot get address information

Tags: android, mapbox

I cannot get address information.

works only in the usa and european countries

```
if (results.size() > 0) {
              CarmenFeature feature = results.get(0);

              // If the geocoder returns a result, we take the first in the list and show a Toast with the place name.
              mapboxMap.getStyle(new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                @Override
                public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                  if (style.getLayer(DROPPED_MARKER_LAYER_ID) != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(LocationPickerActivity.this,
                        String.format(getString(R.string.location_picker_place_name_result),
                            feature.placeName()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                }
              });

            } else {
              Toast.makeText(LocationPickerActivity.this,
                  getString(R.string.location_picker_dropped_marker_snippet_no_results), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

If you mark a region with the USA and European countries with the marker, it gives the address information. But he does not give the address information in Turkey.

[image: screenshot]

mapbox uses Foursquare to get address information in the background.

evidence  :  https://twitter.com/mezbjen/status/1245390171635408900

How do I solve this problem, you know?

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox doesn't have address coverage in that region of Turkey. Use [https://docs.mapbox.com/search-playground/#{%22url%22:%22%22,%22index%22:%22mapbox.places%22,%22approx%22:true,%22staging%22:false,%22onCountry%22:false,%22onType%22:true,%22onProximity%22:false,%22onBBOX%22:false,%22onLimit%22:false,%22onLanguage%22:false,%22countries%22:[],%22proximity%22:%22%22,%22typeToggle%22:{%22country%22:false,%22region%22:false,%22district%22:false,%22postcode%22:false,%22locality%22:false,%22place%22:false,%22neighborhood%22:false,%22address%22:true,%22poi%22:false},%22types%22:[%22address%22],%22bbox%22:%22%22,%22limit%22:%22%22,%22autocomplete%22:false,%22languages%22:[],%22languageStrict%22:false,%22onDebug%22:false,%22selectedLayer%22:%22%22,%22debugClick%22:{},%22localsearch%22:false,%22query%22:%2230.583266,%2040.124899%22}](https://docs.mapbox.com/search-playground/#%7B%22url%22:%22%22,%22index%22:%22mapbox.places%22,%22approx%22:true,%22staging%22:false,%22onCountry%22:false,%22onType%22:true,%22onProximity%22:false,%22onBBOX%22:false,%22onLimit%22:false,%22onLanguage%22:false,%22countries%22:[],%22proximity%22:%22%22,%22typeToggle%22:%7B%22country%22:false,%22region%22:false,%22district%22:false,%22postcode%22:false,%22locality%22:false,%22place%22:false,%22neighborhood%22:false,%22address%22:true,%22poi%22:false%7D,%22types%22:[%22address%22],%22bbox%22:%22%22,%22limit%22:%22%22,%22autocomplete%22:false,%22languages%22:[],%22languageStrict%22:false,%22onDebug%22:false,%22selectedLayer%22:%22%22,%22debugClick%22:%7B%7D,%22localsearch%22:false,%22query%22:%2230.583266,%2040.124899%22%7D) to see what's possible with the Mapbox Geocoding API.

Comment: Hello I understand but why?

Why mapbox api only serves the USA and European countries.

Comment: > Why mapbox api only serves the USA and European countries

Can you say more about what you mean?

Mapbox provides address-level coverage in countries that are not the US or in Europe. For example, click somewhere in Mexico City or Cape Town in the geocoding playground with the address filter enabled.

Unfortunately, Mapbox doesn't have address-level coverage for rural areas of Turkey.

Comment: Istanbul and Ankara, Turkey's my rural region?

If mapbox says it serves at a global level, its api must work all over the world.